# rewrite rule wordpress not working

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, wordpress-theming

This quetsion has been ask al lot, but however I tried I get always a 404 page in WP

I have a templatepage (wp-content/themes/responsivewizzard.php cals: wizzard. -> 
I Added a page in the admin sector. The name of the page = "tespage". The template I choose is "wizzard"
When in try example.com/wp/testpage -> I get my wizzard page. No worries.. but..

I like to add a subpage to my wizzardpage. For example:
example.com/wp/testpage/**nice**

When i try this I get a 404 page from WP

I added this code to my function.php file. This file is in wp-content/themes/responsive directory -> my default theme

```
function members_rewrite_rules()
{
  add_rewrite_rule('testpage /(.+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=testpage &subpage=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'members_rewrite_rules' );

function members_query_vars($query_vars)
{
  $query_vars[] = 'subpage';
  return $query_vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'members_query_vars');
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I found out the soulution. You need to reset the permalinks in the setting menu..